Custom Icon in MarkerComposable don't get updated after update text inside it
I have a map with markers and the marker I add a custom icon to it with a text indicating the sequence of that marker.
and what's happening is when I update these marker sequences it's not get updated and it has the same value once it's recomposed
and I keep track of the follow after updating the sequence it never get into MarkerComposable again
how i can make sure that the text inside the icon got udpated correctly.

data class Pin(
    val location: LatLng,
    val sequence: String
)


    @Composable
fun LocationMarkers(
    locations: List<Pin>,
) {

    locations.onEachIndexed { index, pin ->
        MarkerComposable(
            state = MarkerState(pin.location),
        ) {
            
            Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_order_marker_dark),
                    contentDescription = ""
                )

                Text(
                    text = pin.sequence,
                    color = Color.White,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(top = 4.dp)
                        .align(Alignment.TopCenter)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

